# Mongoose update entire nested elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and MongoDB. Is there any way to update the entire schedule array in the schema? or do I have to use a for loop and insert one by one?
My req.body is an array to replace the entire schedules array object.

```
[{"_id":"1","description":"hi","time":"Jul 29, 2020 8:55 PM","url":"aaa.com"},{"_id":"2","description":"hi","time":"Jul 29, 2020 8:58 PM","url":"bbb.com"},{"_id":"3","description":"hi"}]
```

here is my schema.

```
const schedule = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: Number,
  schedules: [{
    description: String,
    time: String,
    url: String
  }]
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mongoose, we can avoid using `$set`. @jitendra's answer is a pure mongodb query which you could run in the mongo shell.

You can refer to this link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate .
As the link says,

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { name: 'jason bourne' }, options, callback)

// is sent as
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, callback)
```

> This helps prevent accidentally overwriting your document with { name: 'jason bourne' }.

So in your case we just need to write :

`Schedule.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "id_of_object"}, {schedules: req.body});`

That should do it for you. But internally, as the doc says, it is being sent as:

`Schedule.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "id_of_object"}, {$set: {schedules: req.body}})`

Ofcourse this assumes that your `req.body` consists of the array of schedules only. Most likely you're sending it as an object from the front end so maybe it's `req.body.object_name` . Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the entire schedule array by using $set , try as follow:

```
db.collection.update({query},{ $set: { schedules: req.body } },{option});
```

Here your req.body should be the array with same keys as per defined in your schema.